# How to change the content of module that Android Studio's auto-generated?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-plugin

I known there is a thing called template to solve this problem. The question is i want config something when creating module step by step. In other word, i want a more flexible method to generate android module. So i prepare to develop a plugin to do this. And what's more, I know the official plugin use `AndroidModuleBuilder`，`AndroidWizardWrapper` and other classes to generate module. So is there any possibilty to extend official android module function and add some other functions to wizard?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "project template".

Open this folder in the Android Studio installation folder:

```
Android Studio/plugins/android/lib/templates
```

You'll see folders that contains some files ends with ".ftl", just edit them and create a new project again, and you'll see the effect.

To add steps during the module creation, you need to edit and compile your own "Android Support" plugin, AFAIK. Because I don't think they've provided APIs (extension point) for adding steps during module creation.
You may do something in the implementation of `com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleWizardStep#updateDataModel` (executed during the step), and `com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleBuilder#setupRootModel` (executed when you clicked "Finish" button).

You can get the project root directory by `com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModifiableRootModel#getProject`, while `com.intellij.openapi.roots.ModifiableRootModel` is the parameter of `setupRootModel`.

Comment: Yeah, I know where the templates is. But i said changing template couldn't meet my needs. So i prepare to write a plugin to do this. And i don't know how to modify the step of Android module generation by plugin. Can you give me some ideas?

Comment: You can customize the Android plugin (the used by IntelliJ IDEA is available on GitHub, and I just have no idea about Android Studio), because I don't think they've provided API for adding steps

Comment: @leimenghao Edited, added some plugin development related stuffs

Comment: Android studio plugin can be developed by IntelliJ. And Android studio is also a open source project :P.

Comment: Android Studio IDE is different from IntelliJ + Android plugin. I though you've known the difference, though.